# Sort Multidimensional array by two criterias?

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have a multidimensional array which I would like to sort by two factors: First the state and then the city alphabetically.

```
  var locations = [
                ['Baltimore', 'Maryland', 'MD'],
                ['Germantown', 'Maryland', 'MD'],
                ['Rockville', 'Maryland', 'MD'],
                ['San Francisco', 'California', 'CA'],
                ['San Diego', 'California', 'CA']
  ];
```

How can I sort them alphabetically based on these two factors?
First State, then City?
I know how to do it just be one factor, but not two..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
locations.sort(function(x, y) {
   if (x[1] > y[1])       // if you want to sort by abbreviation,
     return 1;            // use [2] instead of [1].
   else if (x[1] < y[1])
     return -1;
   else if (x[0] > y[0])
     return 1;
   else if (x[0] < y[0])
     return -1;
   else
     return 0;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
locations.sort(function(a, b){
  var cmp = function(x, y){ //generic for any sort
     return x > y? -1 : x < y ? 1 : 0; 
  };
  return [cmp(a[1], b[1]), cmp(a[0], b[0])] < 
         [cmp(b[1], a[1]), cmp(b[0], a[0])] ? 1 : -1;
});
```

If you want to sor descending on city for instance you can use `-cmp(...)` instead of `cmp(...)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use "[LINQ for JavaS](http://linqjs.codeplex.com/)cript" library. Very useful library.

Answer (score 1):

Use a custom sort callback:

```
locations.sort(function(a, b)
{
    if (a[1] < b[1])
    {
        return -1;
    }
    if (a[1] > b[1])
    {
        return 1;
    }
    if (a[0] < b[0])
    {
        return -1;
    }
    if (a[0] > b[0])
    {
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with fewer else ifs- may make a difference if you have a lot of cities.

```
var locations= [
    ['Baltimore','Maryland','MD'],
    ['Germantown','Maryland','MD'],
    ['Rockville','Maryland ','MD'],
    ['San Francisco','California','CA'],
    ['San Diego','California','CA']
    ];

locations.sort(function(a, b){
    if(a[1]===b[1]){
        if(a[0]===b[0]) return 0;
        return a[0]>b[0]? 1:-1;
    }
    return a[1]>b[1]? 1:-1;
})

//alert(locations.join('\n'))
locations.join('\n')

/*  returned value: (String)
San Diego,California,CA
San Francisco,California,CA
Baltimore,Maryland,MD
Germantown,Maryland,MD
Rockville,Maryland ,MD
*/
```